# Headphone Jack White Noise

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones

I have an Asus N551VW Laptop running ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have a weird problem, when I plug in headphones, I am getting high pitched white noise. I have tried muting every channel with alsamixer but did not solve the issue. I have also tried modifying the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file and adding one of these entries at the end

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-headset-multi
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

But this way I was getting no sound at all on the headphones.

I have also tried with different headphones thinking it may be more of a hardware issue, but the result was the same.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling Auto-Mute in AlsaMixer? That's what worked for me.

I have a Surface Book 2 dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. There was a hissing, white noise sound coming from the headphone jack once I plugged in my headphones, only in Ubuntu.